# Manga where a reincarnated(?) young boy has a maid and a wolf girl who he does business with

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a manga, and is likely to be a light novel adaptation. I can't remember if this is actually a reincarnation/isekai story, but I do remember it being set in a fantasy world. I read this sometime last year before MangaDex's maintenance break.

I recall the male protagonist being a merchant or similar occupation, and was business partners with a wolf girl. The wolf girl may have been described as a lycanthrope. She had droopy ears, and I distinctly remember there was a comment about her species only letting special people touch their ears, and hinted that the boy could touch her ears. She had a thorny personality to others except for the boy.

The boy also had a maid, who loves (or respects) the boy. The maid was competitive with the wolf girl for the boy's attention, knowing that the wolf girl likes the boy.

The boy MAY have went to school, and for some reason had to move. The wolf girl moved her business location to operate close to him.

Comment: Welcome! Please see our guide on [how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) (e.g., when did you read this?).

Comment: Did he have a special power based on the powers of the people he held as slaves?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I don't think he had slaves. He may have had a special power himself, though. Sorry for the vagueness, I can't recall exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for *Isekai Tensei Soudouki* by Honoji and Takami Ryousen.

> Balud Cornelius is the son of a noble of the Mauricia kingdom and inside him also dwell the souls of the stingy warring states commander Okasanai Sadatoshi and animal ear otaku high-schooler Oka Masaharu. With these 3 souls in a single body, he can exhibit extraordinary abilities when it comes to combat or managing the domain.

> Petting the droopy ears

[image: Petting the droopy ears]

> Only special people allowed to pet

[image: Only special people allowed to pet]

Comment: Thanks so much! Yea I remember reading "therianthrope" and googling what it meant at the time. I got it confused with lycanthrope.